# Need help clicking an ```<a href="">``` element that doesn't have any identifiers

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script that comments on a certain post then clicks on the "Favourite this post" button but this button doesn't have any sort of ID assigned to it how would I click this button?

I've tried JQuery but it didn't work.

I'm trying to use this on [FurAffinity](http://www.furaffinity.net) to automatically click an `<a>` element without any sort of identifiers. When i check the element with dev. options on google it says that the name exists, it's just set to blank so I cannot choose it with JQuery.

The snippet example of the code of the website. I would like to click the "+Add to Favourites" text using a separate button that appears elsewhere on the page by the use of Tampermonkey.

I don't know how I would find the element by using just the InnerHTML of it. The `<a>` tag has no name or id or class, just an href and some text inside.

```html
<div class="alt1 actions aligncenter" style="margin-top: 8px;">
                
                                    <b><a href="/fav/33151503/?key=37dfe6a83f38f48790a6551921ddb13850e2c6a0">+Add to Favorites</a></b> |
                                <b><a href="//d.facdn.net/art/legacy2988/stories/1569252982/1569252982.legacy2988_i’m_not_sure_atm.txt">Download</a></b> |
                <b><a href="/full/33151503/">Full View</a></b>

                
                                    | <b><a href="/newpm/legacy2988/">Send note</a></b>
                
                
                <div>Submission &copy; 2019 Legacy2988</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Would you like to share your code? What you have done so far and where you are getting an issue. Better to show on Jsfiddle so people can help you more precisely.

Comment: jquery definitely should work. `$(this).closest('a').click()` if you share your code we can help you more

Comment: There's no such thing as an "href element". There is an anchor element (`<a>`) which allows an `href` attribute, but that's not a button.

Comment: Show us the html.

Comment: @AbdulhaqShah The post has been updated!

Comment: @goldie The post has been updated!

Comment: @HereticMonkey The post has been updated!

Comment: @Moob The post has been updated!

Comment: Explaining us why there's no code is useless. We can only help if you show us what you've tried but also and foremost the HTML code you're trying to act onto. How can we help finding a selector if we don't see the HTML structure?

Comment: The reason that seeing the code matters is that we might be able to target the `a` element by other means. Perhaps it's the _only_ `a`, perhaps its a sibling or child of an element we can easily target, perhaps there's something unique in the text of the `a`?

Comment: @Moob , The element is a child of a ```<b>``` element, i believe. I have linked the page and i'm currently working on a JSFiddle to show a representation of my issue without copying the entire sites HTML. I will comment again once it's finished.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Legacy2988/r56j9umL/1/ This should link directly to an example of the way the bottom of a post looks, i'm trying to click the "+Add to Favourites" button by clicking on a separate link through GM.

Comment: Looks like that's the first `a` in the `.actions` element. So: `document.querySelector(".actions a").click();` should work.

Comment: So, now we have a link to the code, that's progress. Now all you need to do is copy and paste that code into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) here on Stack Overflow, which is what the close reason says to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample code, you want to find this element:

```
<a href="/fav/33151503/?key=37dfe6a83f38f48790a6551921ddb13850e2c6a0">+Add to Favorites</a>
```

Assuming there is only 1 such link and it always has `/fav/` in its `href`

```
document.querySelector('a[href*="/fav/"]').click();
```

Above can be further fine-tuned, if necessary but that should give you an idea.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to use this on stackoverflow, the "favorite this post" button has classes that uniquely identify it.

`document.querySelector('.js-favorite-btn').click();`

If you mean some other site with a similar button, likewise check for unique classes, name, and even attributes (e.g. custom data-x attributes) which can all be query selected.

Lastly, as a last resort, you can traverse the dom in the query selector with something like

`document.querySelector('#mainbar > .question div.post-layout button').click();`

mdn [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately i'm not trying to use SO as the site, rather im trying to use "http://www.furaffinity.net as the website. The site has just simple text set as the button and this text leads into a link just link the ```<a>``` tag. The links for every posts' "favourite" is different for every one of them. Also, i updated the post to include more detailed info.